# VS Code installed on Windows 10 - no intergrated terminal

Tags: windows-10, command-line, visual-studio-code

I just installed VS Code for Windows 10 on my laptop.  I am running it also on my desktop, so I know how it should work.
At very first entry, I opened a new terminal.  It opened but an external command prompt window also opened running cmd.exe.  I am unable to get a command prompt at the terminal - just the external window.  When I close the external window, the internal VSCode terminal also closes.  I can find no suggestion anywhere on how to fix this.
the path in the external command prompt is: PS C:\Users\Micky>  I am Micky.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the SuperUser community.

Try this:

Open the VS Code 'settings'
Go to 'Features' (in the left colon)
Click on 'Terminal'
Check the first setting: 'Explorer Kind' => Integrated (must be selected)